# How do I write query to sum the order qty between the Max and Min date of demands? Here is my current query that I am getting an error for:

Tags: sql

```
select 
"Part Number",
max(cast("Order Date" as varchar(15))) as "Max Date",
min(cast("Order  Date" as varchar(15))) as "Min Date",
(sum("Order Qty") between "Max Date" and "Min Date") as "Total Demand"
from table 1
group by "Part Number"
```

I tried converting the Order Dates to numeric values instead of dates to use the between function. I am getting an error that "Numeric value '2024-03-08' is not found". My goal is to sum the order qty between two dates (Max Date and Min Date).

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected result? By definition, disregarding nulls, all orders would fall between the min and max right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.